# Could there be an RSS feed for the newest Featured questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, feed

It's nice that there's a feed for questions ending soonest, but I'd like it the other way around, an RSS feed for featured questions that just appeared. Could there be such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible. I have written a small app called [stack2rss](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service) that converts API requests into RSS feeds.

The one that does what you've described is here:

http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/stackoverflow/questions?sort=featured&body=true

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's possible without the use of an external tool.

Just build the url yourself:

e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/javascript?sort=featured

Comment: But only by tag, not for all the site. Still a nice one.

Answer (score 2):

This has been possible for a while; see

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/featured

aka the RSS icon at the bottom of the page when you are on the featured tab:

https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured